# iOS/Swift: Can't assign optional String to UILabel text property

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uilabel, option-type

UILabel has a text property, which is an optional String, but it seems to be behaving like an implicitly unwrapped optional. Why can't I assign it another optional String?  Thanks.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tweetContent: UILabel!
```

...

```
var unopt: String = "foo"
var opt: String? = "bar"
var opt2: String?
opt2 = opt                       //Works fine
cell.tweetContent.text? = unopt  //Works fine
cell.tweetContent.text? = opt    //Compile error: Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to unwrap `text`.

Leaving `text` as an `String?` (aka `Optional<String>`)

```
cell.tweetContent.text = unopt // Works: String implicitly wraps to Optional<String>
cell.tweetContent.text = opt   // Works: Optional<String>
```

Where as unwrapping `text` turns `String?` into a `String`.

```
cell.tweetContent.text? = unopt // Works: String
cell.tweetContent.text? = opt   // Fails: Optional<String> cannot become String
```

---

**UPDATE**

Maybe there needs to be a bit more of an explanation here. `text?` is worse than I originally thought and should not be used.

Think of `text = value` and `text? = value` as function `setText`.

`text =` has the signature `func setText(value: String?)`. Remember, `String?` is `Optional<String>`. In addition, it's always called no matter the current value of `text`.

`text? =` has the signature `func setText(value: String)`. Here is the catch, it's only called when `text` has a value.

```
cell.tweetContent.text = nil
cell.tweetContent.text? = "This value is not set"
assert(cell.tweetContent == nil)
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to learn more about this, is there a specific name for adding the question mark to the left operand of an assignment?