# Why can't I assign a value to a Measurement<UnitMass> variable?

Tags: swift, swift3, measurement

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to assign the result of a calculation a variable, `fileprivate var oneRepMax: Measurement<UnitMass>?` As you can see, it's an optional and it simply stays nil after I try to assign a value to it.

I originally tried to make a direct assignment to the .`value` property like so:

```
oneRepMax?.value = liftWeight * (Double(repetitions) ^^ 0.10)
```

but that didn't work. I then determined I need to specify the `unit` (based on the current user default unit) during the assignment so I tried this (here's the full context):

```
func calculateOneRepMax() -> Measurement<UnitMass> {

 let defaultWeightUnit = UserDefaults.weightUnit().unitName <-- returns "kg"
 let unit = UnitMass(symbol: defaultWeightUnit) <-- 'po unit' shows <NSUnitMass: 0x61000003ffa0> kg
 switch withFormula {        
     case "Lombardi":
        let result = liftWeight * (Double(repetitions) ^^ 0.10)
        oneRepMax? = Measurement(value: result, unit: unit)
     *case next case...*
}
```

I really thought that would work but still, oneRepMax is nil.

I've read through Apple's documentation and even reviewed some Ray Wenderlich screencasts but haven't figured out that answer. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
oneRepMax? = Measurement(value: result, unit: unit)
```

to:

```
oneRepMax = Measurement(value: result, unit: unit)
```

If `oneRepMax` is an optional value currently with a `nil` value, then the assignment doesn't happen when you use `oneRepMax? = ...`.

The answer to [iOS/Swift: Can't assign optional String to UILabel text property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608649/ios-swift-cant-assign-optional-string-to-uilabel-text-property) is related and provides a bit more explanation.

Comment: Just when I thought I had optionals figured out...oh well. Thanks!